# Making a method inside an array ? or shorter?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to make this somehow shorter or take less space.

```
 totalTime = [self timeFormatted:([currentFeed duration].intValue)-1];
    NSString *word = @":00:";
    if ([totalTime rangeOfString:word].location == NSNotFound) {
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"00:" withString:@""];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"01:" withString:@"1:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"02:" withString:@"2:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"03:" withString:@"3:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"04:" withString:@"4:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"05:" withString:@"5:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"06:" withString:@"6:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"07:" withString:@"7:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"08:" withString:@"8:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"09:" withString:@"9:"];
    }
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make totalTime a mutableString. You can then put your mapping into an NSDictionary and iterate on it.

```
NSMutableString *ms = [[totalTime mutableCopy] autorelease];

NSDictionary *d = @{@"00":@"", @"01:":@"1:", @"02:":@"2:" /* ... */};

[d enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [ms replaceOccurrencesOfString:key withString:obj options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [ms length])];
}];

totalTime = ms;
```

By the way, if you're trying to format a date, have a look at [NSDateFormatter reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: NSDictionary *d = {@"00":@"", @"01:":@"1:", @"02:":@"2:"};

I tried this and I get this error ' Expected "}" '

Comment: Your compiler probably doesn't use Objective-C literals.

Try declaring the dictionary this way:

`NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"", @"00", @"1:", @"01:", @"2:", @"02:", /* ... */ nil];`

Comment: you're missing a @ in front of the curved braces: `NSDictionary *d = @{@"00":@"", @"01:":@"1:", @"02:":@"2:"};`

Comment: Thank you @Herm I blame Python for this typo! :)

Answer (score 1):

Taking a different approach with regular expressions:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
// replace 0X: with X: where X is 1-9
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"0([1-9]:)" options:0 error:&error];
date = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:date options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,date.length) withTemplate:@"$1"];

// remove 00: if not preceded by :
regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<!:)00:" options:0 error:&error];
date = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:date options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,date.length) withTemplate:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

add a Category for NSString:

```
@implementation NSString (replace)

-(void) replace:(NSString*)old with:(NSString*)new{

self = [self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:old  withString:new];
}
```

so you have to call only:
`[totalTime replace:@"00:" with:@""];`